# How to achieve the material removal material from Solids? (Like the CAM simulation)

Tags: c#, user-interface, graphics, simulation, augmented-reality

I am working on a project to simulate the machine cutting process through Augmented Reality, i.e one object “removes material” from another object. For instance, a drill enters a piece of wood and a hole can be seen when the drill is withdrawn. Can anyone please point out a direction or approach that would accomplish this? I don’t mind researching and learning what is needed, hints and suggestions will be great, free libraries and/or technique examples would be even better. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There is no information in your question that would allow someone to answer with an answer much more than "well, you'll need to write some code". Sorry, but your question isn't a good fit for this site. I expect it will  e closed soon

Comment: Check out [constructive solid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry).  This is a trivial thing to do with _ray tracing_